# How to work with PHP str_replace working with condition

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using str_replace function to remove some characters from string
Like if:

```
$phone = "+92300-7881292";

$phone = str_replace("-","",$phone);

$phone = str_replace("+","",$phone);
```

the output is correct:

```
$phone = "923007881292";
```

But I want to replace first 2 characters of i.e 92
I want if there is 92 in first 2 characters then it replace with 0. But when i use this code

```
$phone = str_replace("92","",$phone);
```

It will remove all 92 characters from string.

Please help

Comment: `$phone = str_replace(["+92", '-', '+'],["0",'',''],$phone);`

Comment: `$phone = preg_replace("/^92/", "", $phone);` (also, if you start with replacing `+92` you don't have to worry about matches for 92 later)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a specific string from the start of another string, `ltrim` may come in quite handy:

```php
$phone = ltrim($phone, '92');
```

In case you have further conditions you want to do, in case it really starts with `92`, you can use `str_starts_with`:

```php
if (str_starts_with($phone, '92')) {
    $phone = ltrim($phone, '92');
    // Also do something else...
}
```

If you use anything lower than PHP 8, you can not use `str_starts_with`, so you may want to check it like this:

```php
if (substr($phone, 0, strlen('92')) === '92') {
    $phone = ltrim($phone, '92');
    // Also do something else...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for removing the first 2 characters from string :

```
$phone = "+92300-7881292";
$phone = str_replace("-","",$phone);
$phone = str_replace("+","",$phone);

$firstTwoCharacters = substr($phone, 0, 2);

// Now match first two characters
if($firstTwoCharacters == '92'){
  $phone = substr($phone, 2); // It will remove first two characters from string
  $phone = '0' . $phone;
}
echo $phone;
```

Output: **03007881292**

Comment: But the required output is `03007881292`

Comment: You can simply prepend the zero to the final output :
$phone = "0".$phone;
echo $phone;

Comment: But only needss that IF the first 2 numbers are 92, so this really is not much of an answer

Comment: I have edited my solution and changed the code, so now it is showing results as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below script.

```
<?php
$phone = "+92300-7881292";

// Find and replace in the string
$phone = str_replace("-","",$phone);

$phone = str_replace("+","",$phone);

// Get first two numbers from the phone variable
$firstTwoNumbers = substr($phone, 0, 2);

// Get other numbers from the phone variable
$restOfTheNumbers = substr($phone, 2);

// Check if 92 exists
if($firstTwoNumbers == "92") {
    // Concatenate the values
    $prefixNumber = 0;
    $newPhone = $prefixNumber .''. $restOfTheNumbers;
} else {
    // Set the default value or do something else
    $newPhone = $phone;
}

// Output
print $newPhone;

?>
```

**Output - 03007881292**

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
$phone = "+92300-7881292";

$phone = str_replace(["+92", '-', '+'],["0",'',''],$phone);
```

Comment: Some people get a bit annoyed when you take a comment and make it into your answer :)

Comment: I think it's just a coincidence that we gave the same answer because where I sent the code in I didn't see your answer. :)

Comment: I don't see a problem with copying comments - the commenter chose to make a comment and not an answer. Fair enough. The problem here is that there is no explanation for the code.

Comment: It does not matter now whether comment or answer

Comment: Comments are not for answers. My recommendation would be if you dont want someone to "steal" your answer from a comment, just post it as an answer instead. Failing to do that, someone else 100% can repost it as an answer. That's what this site is for, questions and answers - not questions and comments.
Side note: Please only downvote if this answer is wrong, not because you perceive some injustice. That said, giving credit is nice when needed. See this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why don't you just post it as an answer yourself? Its probably annoying but its the commenter's own fault for posting answers in comments. But yeah about the answer quality, this is indeed a bad answer as it does not provide any explanations to the code

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Sorry I started all this, by the way I did not Downvote this answer